# Work manager periodic job not working on chinese ROMs once app is force closed

Tags: android, androidx, android-workmanager

I have tried stack overflow but people only added Android documentation which says it'll work but it doesn't i have also raised an issue in google's issue tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120811754).

I have tested on Android versions: 6, 7, 8 and work manager 1.0.0-alpha11, 1.0.0-alpha12

If anyone has found any solution for running periodic job please comment it'll be a great help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and, [as commented in this other bug on Google's issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/113676489), there's not much that WorkManager can do in these cases.

As commented in this bug:

> ...if a device manufacturer has decided to modify stock Android to force-stop the app, WorkManager will stop working (as will JobScheduler, alarms, broadcast receivers, etc.).  There is no way to work around this.  Some device manufacturers do this, unfortunately, so in those cases WorkManager will stop working until the next time the app is launched.

Comment: Actually i had seen that i still thought if there was any work around for that. Anyway thanks for clearing my doubt